# PHP - Sessions and REST

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I need help with understanding what I am doing wrong.
I am building RESTful API for inner use.
I have 2 endpoints - /login and /logout.
On login I am validating user input and creating a session - Works good.
On logout I would like to destroy the session but it says "**session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in...**"

Here is the code:

**Login:**

```
$api->post('/login', function () {
if(some validations)
{
    session_name('lalala');
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), 0, '/', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', false, true);
}
});
```

**Logout:**

```
$api->post('/logout', function () {
session_unset();
session_destroy(); // here it fails

setcookie('lalala', "", 1);
setcookie('lalala', false);
unset($_COOKIE);

});
```

Please note, I am using an IP address instead of a domain name. I don't believe there is a difference but for your attention.

Can you please help me understand what is wrong here?

Comment: Add `session_start();` at the begginig of **logout.php** file

Comment: What do you need sessions for?

Comment: Can you please help me understand what is the logic behind this? I would like to kill the session. For what reason I need to start it before?

Comment: You have to start the session to get lock of the session file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call:

```
session_name('lalala');
session_start();
```

before `session_unset()`

Instead of `setcookie(...)` use `session_set_cookie_params()` before `session_start()`